# Format each row in a dynamic table using javascript - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table, xhtml

im creating a dynamic table in a html form using the next function:

```
<script>
    function poblarTabla() {

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement('table');

        // SET THE TABLE ID. 
        // WE WOULD NEED THE ID TO TRAVERSE AND EXTRACT DATA FROM THE TABLE.
        table.setAttribute('id', 'tablaDeCuentas');

        var arrHead = new Array();
        arrHead = ['Emp. ID', 'Emp.Name', 'Designation'];

        var arrValue = new Array();
        arrValue.push(['1', 'Green Field', 'Accountant']);
        arrValue.push(['2', 'Arun Banik', 'Project Manager']);
        arrValue.push(['3', 'Dewane Paul', 'Programmer']);

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var h = 0; h < arrHead.length; h++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');              // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = arrHead[h];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        for (var c = 0; c <= arrValue.length - 1; c++) {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < arrHead.length; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');          // TABLE DEFINITION.
                td = tr.insertCell(-1);
                td.innerHTML = arrValue[c][j];                  // ADD VALUES TO EACH CELL.
            }
        }


        document.body.appendChild(table);

    }

</script>
```

This works correctly, what i want to do now is format each row using this format:

```
<tr align="left" valign="middle"><td bgcolor="#005C84" width="240" height="30"> <p style="color: white; font-size: 14px;font-family: Arial,sans-serif;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none; display:block; padding:0; margin:0; margin-left:10px">ID de cuenta:</p></td><td bgcolor="#e5f0c3"><p style="color: #666; font-size: 14px;font-family: Arial,sans-serif;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none; display:block; padding:0; margin:0; margin-left:10px"></p></td></tr>
```

So each time that a row is created, is displayed in the form with this format. Can anyome give me a hand? Thnks in advance!

Comment: just apply a `css` class to the elements which contains your style definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using inline styles, you can try creating classes and then add them as you like while you are creating the table or its rows.

style.css

```
.table-style{
    align: left;
    valign: middle;
}
```

then in your javascript:

```
table.classList.add('table-style');
```

Comment: Can i use this method classList.add with the tr and td elemets too?

Comment: Yes you can do that, also, it will cause all your tr elements to have same style and all td to have same.